# SDWebImage: Cache-Control Header is not used

Tags: sdwebimage

I'm loading my images in my UICollectionView with `UIImageView+WebCache` category. I'm using the option `SDWebImageRefreshCached`:

```
[cell.imageView
 setImageWithURL:url
 placeholderImage:nil
 options:SDWebImageRefreshCached | SDWebImageRetryFailed
 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) 
{
    if (error) NSLog(@"Error loading image");
}
```

The Cache-Control of the image is `public, max-age=604772`. If I activate the airplane mode, I get the "Error loading image" message.

Why is SDWebImage trying to connect the web server every time, although the max-age is set to 1 week?

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImageRefreshCached ignores the cached image and will always try to get a fresh image from the url. Omit SDWebImageRefreshCached and the cached image will be used